# position of elements in a expanded div depending on scroll position

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, expand

I've been reading many threads here about scroll position but can't make it work. I'm using a JS plugin to create a grid of images, when I click on any of this images (.imagewrap) it expands a div (.colio-content) that is generated dynamically using JS, with further content inside. It also moves the scroll bar to place that div on top of the window.

Inside the div I have some navigation elements, such a close button (.colio-close, used to collapse the div) and next/previous arrows (.colio-prev and .colio-next) to go to the next and previous content. They all have a fixed position at beginning and when user scrolls down I change them to an absolute position. What I try to do is change them again to a fixed position when scroll reaches certain position to keep them always inside the div. I've tried to do some simple arithmetic based on scroll position and div height, but it is not working as you can see here

http://neuryvas.com/pruebas/

The JS code I have is something like this

```
$('.imagewrap').on('click', function() {

    var $expandedHigh = $('.colio-content').height();
    var $expandedHighPercent = Math.round($expandedHigh/100);
    var $expandedHighTen = $expandedHighPercent*10;
    var $expandedHighTwenty = $expandedHighPercent*20;
    var $expandedHighThirty = $expandedHighPercent*30;


    $(function () {

        var $win = $(window);
        var $pos = 100;
        var $newPos = ($expandedHigh-$expandedHighTwenty);

        $win.scroll(function () {

            if ($win.scrollTop() <= $pos ){

                $('.colio-close').css({position: 'absolute',  top: ($expandedHighPercent*4)});
                $('.colio-prev, .colio-no-prev, .colio-next, .colio-no-next').css({position: 'absolute', top: ($expandedHighPercent*16)});

            }else{

                if ($win.scrollTop() >= $newPos){


                        $('.colio-close').css({position: 'absolute',  top: ($expandedHigh - $expandedHighTwenty)});
                        $('.colio-prev, .colio-no-prev, .colio-next, .colio-no-next').css({position: 'absolute', top: ($expandedHigh - $expandedHighTen)});


                }else{

                        if ($windowWidth <= 665){

                            $('.colio-close').css({position: 'fixed', top: ($expandedHighPercent*4.5)});
                            $('.colio-prev, .colio-no-prev, .colio-next, .colio-no-next').css({position: 'fixed', top: ($expandedHighPercent*16)});

                        }else{

                            $('.colio-close').css({position: 'fixed', top: ($expandedHighPercent*3)});
                            $('.colio-prev, .colio-no-prev, .colio-next, .colio-no-next').css({position: 'fixed', top: ($expandedHighPercent*16)});

                        }
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Would you gimme a hand with this, please? Not sure how to control this parameters and if I using the best way to achieve this.

Many thanks

Comment: i can help you. But plese provide FULL HTML of your webpage. And change all of css, js and image files on that HTML to FULL URL contains http://neuryvas.com/pruebas/

Comment: Hi Kamarul, many thanks for reply. I'd love if you can help me with this, but not sure what you need, mate. I'll be happy to give you all you might need. I cannot provide the entire HTML in a comment here I'm afraid, it is too long. Same with CSS and JS. I thought with the URL will be enough. Sorry in case I misunderstood you. Please lemme know what you need and I will give it to you but I cannot paste the entire code in here.

Many thanks for your help